# Composer message: requirements could not be resolved

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, jms, sonata

Im trying to update symfony via composer.
I resolved most of the issues in my package, but cant seem to resolve this.
This error is just not making sense to me.

If anyone can help, would be great!

```
    Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package sonata-project/notification-bundle (installed at 2.3.0, required as 3.1.0) is satisfiable by sonata-project/notification-bundle[2.3.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for jms/security-extra-bundle 1.6.1 -> satisfiable by jms/security-extra-bundle[1.6.1].
    - Can only install one of: jms/security-extra-bundle[1.6.1, 1.5.x-dev].
    - Installation request for jms/security-extra-bundle (installed at 1.5.x-dev, required as 1.6.1) -> satisfiable by jms/security-extra-bundle[1.5.x-dev].
```

Here are the required packages:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/icu": "1.1.0",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.6",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",

    "liip/theme-bundle": "1.2.*@dev",

    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle": "~1.5",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "2.0.*@dev",
    "pugx/multi-user-bundle": "3.0.*@dev",

    "doctrine/orm": "2.*",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.3.*",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "2.1.*@dev",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "2.2.*@dev",
    "stof/doctrine-extensions-bundle": "1.1.*@dev",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.2",

    "knplabs/gaufrette": "0.2.*@dev",
    "knplabs/knp-gaufrette-bundle": "0.2.*@dev",
    "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "2.4.*@dev",

    "jms/security-extra-bundle": "1.6.1",
    "jms/serializer-bundle": "0.13.*@dev",

    "oneup/uploader-bundle": "0.9.*@dev",

    "egeloen/google-map": "1.4.*@dev",
    "egeloen/google-map-bundle": "2.2.*@dev",
    "marlon-be/marlon-ogone": "1.0.*@stable",

    "simplethings/form-extra-bundle": "^1.1",
    "neutron/recaptcha": "dev-master",
    "phpro/chili-xml-parser": "dev-master",
    "phpro/chili-soap": "dev-master",
    "activecampaign/api-php": "~1.0",
    "videlalvaro/php-amqplib": "~2.4",

    "sonata-project/datagrid-bundle": "2.2.*@dev",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "3.1.4",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "3.18.2",
    "sonata-project/page-bundle": "3.4.1",
    "sonata-project/notification-bundle": "3.1.0",
    "sonata-project/easy-extends-bundle": "~2.1",
    "sonata-project/translation-bundle": "dev-master",
    "sonata-project/formatter-bundle": "3.2.1",
    "sonata-project/media-bundle": "3.5.1",
    "sonata-project/intl-bundle": "2.2.0",
    "sonata-project/seo-bundle": "2.0@dev",
    "michelf/php-markdown": "1.4.0",
    "knplabs/knp-markdown-bundle": "^1.4",
    "sonata-project/classification-bundle": "3.0.0",

    "sylius/cart": "0.12.*",
    "sylius/resource": "0.12.*",
    "sylius/order": "0.12.*",
    "sylius/sequence": "0.12.*",
    "sylius/originator": "0.12.*",
    "sylius/registry": "0.12.*",
    "sylius/storage": "0.12.*",
    "sylius/cart-bundle": "0.12.*",
    "sylius/resource-bundle": "0.12.*",
    "sylius/sequence-bundle": "0.12.*",
    "sylius/money-bundle": "0.12.*",
    "sylius/order-bundle": "0.12.*",
    "sylius/promotion-bundle": "0.12.*",
    "sylius/flow-bundle": "0.12.*",
    "sylius/addressing-bundle": "0.12.*",
    "sylius/shipping-bundle": "0.12.*",
    "winzou/state-machine-bundle": "0.2.*",
    "sylius/payment-bundle": "0.12.*",
    "sylius/payum-bundle": "0.12.*",
    "sylius/currency-bundle": "0.12.*",
    "sylius/currency": "dev-bugfixes as 0.12.0.0",
    "sylius/pricing-bundle": "0.12.*",
    "sylius/taxation-bundle": "0.12.*",

    "payum/payum": "~0.12.0",
    "payum/payum-bundle": "~0.12.2",
    "friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle": "~3.1",
    "setasign/fpdi": "^1.5",
    "setasign/fpdi_pdf-parser": "^1.1",
    "ddeboer/vatin-bundle": "^1.0",
    "ruflin/elastica": "dev-bugfix as 2.0.0",
    "setasign/fpdf": "^1.7",
    "symfony/var-dumper": "^3.1"
}
```

Comment: Please add your `composer.json` file and the complete entered command on your post.

Comment: Which version of Symfony are you using?

Comment: I'm updating from 2.3 to 2.8. Might update to 3 after some adjustments.

Comment: I checked all versions for stability, they are all stable. But even if i change mininum stability to "dev" it still gives me this conflict.

Answer (score 0):

!!! THIS IS NOT THE BETTER SOLUTION !!! .. but is a solution.

I often delete the composer.lock file before, and after I run the composer install. This often solve my issues.

Comment: Delete composer.lock IS NOT A GOOD SOLUTION.

Comment: I know, but is A solution.

Answer (score 0):

I updated another dependency and ran composer install.
All is good now.

Comment: which dependency is that?